# How we can launch a JS program with this command ./prog.js?

Tags: javascript, shell

I had to launch the following code :

```
    var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

str.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
    return console.log(
    s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy'
        : s === 'alicia'
        ? 'girl'
        : s === 'cookie'
        ? 'dog'
        : 'unknown');
});
```

with this command : `./prog.js`

But it does not work and I found online in order to launch a JS program on a terminal we had to use this command : `node prog.js`.
And my internship supervisor said to me the first command it's very possible. So can you help me in order to launch my code with the first command please?

Comment: [article](http://2ality.com/2011/12/nodejs-shell-scripting.html)

Comment: You need to make the file executable with `chmod +x <file>` and then add the "shebang" comment to the top of your file: `#!/usr/bin/env node`.

Comment: @meagar what's the point of using `env` there? I see that a lot but I don't get why it's necessary; `#!node` works just fine.

Comment: if you did not use you have this error > `bash: ./prog.js: node: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` @Pointy

Comment: Thank you @meagar for you answer

Comment: @cpeUser2018 huh well it works fine for me (Ubuntu 16.04) so long as node is in my `PATH`. That is, `which node` gives me `/usr/local/bin/node` so that's what `exec` will use.